# React: Typescript not recognizing intrinsic attributes when extending HTMLAnchorElement

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, intrinsicattributes

I have a simple anchor tag component that extends the native `<a>` tag.

I've defined my typescript interface to extend `React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement>`, but when I attempt to use component `A` and pass props like `rel` and `target` I get IntrinsicAttributes errors.

How can I extend the anchor tag properly?

Component definition:

```
interface Props extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> {
  href: string;
  className?: string;
}

export const A: FC<Props> = ({ href, className, children, ...rest }) => {
  const baseClasses = "text-mb-green-200";
  const classes = `${baseClasses} ${className ? className : ""}`;

  return (
    <a {...rest} href={href} className={classes}>
      {children}
    </a>
  );
};
```

Attempted use:

```
<A {...rest} href={href} className={classes} rel={rel} target={target}>
   {children}
</A>
```

TS Error:

```
Type '{ children: ReactNode; href: string; className: string; target: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'rel' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props & { children?: ReactNode; }'.ts(2322)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `React.AnchorHTMLAttributes` instead of `React.HTMLAttributes`.

I found this out by looking in the `node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts` file and doing a file-search for `rel?:`

```
interface Props extends React.AnchorHTMLAttributes<HTMLAnchorElement> {

}
```

[image]